# Mockito - Verify that a static method inside an Object's method is called

Tags: mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have a problem like this

```
public class ErrorLog {
     public static void increment(String exception) {
          // do something
     }
}

import ErrorLog;
public class Calculator {
     public int division(int a, int b) {
          if (b == 0) {
               ErrorLog.increment("Divide by Zero");
          } else {
               return a / b;
          }
     }
}
```

I want to verify the number of calls to divide, but when I have divide by zero situation, somehow verify that the static method ErrorLog.increment is called (with the exact string as the parameter).

With Mockito spy, I can do something like this to ensure calls to the divide method.

```
Calculator c = new Calculator();
Calculator calcSpy = spy(c);

c.division(6, 3);
c.division(1, 0);

verify(calcSpy, times(2)).division(anyInt(), anyInt());
```

I also keen to verify something like this

```
verify(ErrorLog, times(1)).increment("Divide by Zero");
```

I explored PowerMockito verifyStatic constructs and mockStatic, checked this one too [mockito verify method call inside method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452240/mockito-verify-method-call-inside-method) but in my case the method that is called inside the object is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right `verifyStatic` doesn't have any ways to check the method being called.

But there is a workaround. See if this works for you.

The way to mock a static method is to use

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ErrorLog.class)
```

But you can also use another variant

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ErrorLog.class, invocationOnMock -> {
        assertEquals("something", invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(0, String.class));
        return null;
    });
ErrorLog.increment("something");
```

If you do not mock ErrorLog class, you cannot verify

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick to me, there is a slight change in the method signature, probably we are using the different version of the library, otherwise, it's perfect. (see my solution).

Answer (score 1):

you are right.
If you use a static method you will have problems with tests and dependency injection and this is a case.

You should transform the ErrorLog in a Singleton and then you could verify it with spy.
ex:

```
public class ErrorLog {         
    private static ErrorLog = new ErrorLog();

    public static ErrorLog getInstance() {
        return errorLog;
    }

    public void increment(String exception) {
    // do something
    }
}

import ErrorLog;
public class Calculator {
    public int division(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            ErrorLog.getInstance()increment("Divide by Zero");
        } else {
            return a / b;
        }
    }
}
```

And from this point you can you the following snippet to test the invocations:

```
ErrorLog errorLog = ErrorLog.getInstance();
ErrorLog errorLogSpy = spy(errorLog);

verify(errorLogSpy , times(1)).increment(any());
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, it guided me in the right direction. The thing that did the trick to me is this (I am using TestNG framework).

```
package com.apple.sample.powermock;

import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

@PrepareForTest({ErrorLog.class})
public class TestStaticMethods extends PowerMockTestCase {
    @Test
    public void testSpy() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ErrorLog.class, invocation -> {
            assertEquals("Division by Zero", invocation.getArgument(0, String.class));
                return null;
                });

        new Math().division(10, 0);
    }
}
```